# Stored procedure for inserting columns and rows into another table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How to insert one table columns and records as rows into another table.
Ex: i have one table it contains order id, items, qty
i want to insert those items and columns as rows into another table

Ex : Stored Procedure In Parameter is **order_id**
 Assume order_id=2

```
   select item1,item2,item3,item4,order_qty from ext_door where order_id=order_id

    loop the rows
    {

    if(item1!='')
      {
      insert into order_items (order_id,item_id,qty) values    (order_id,item1,order_qty );
      update item_master set pre_allocated=pre_allocated+order_qty where    item_id=item1;
      }

    if(item2!='')
      {
     insert into order_items (order_id,item_id,qty) values (order_id,item2,order_qty );
     update item_master set pre_allocated=pre_allocated+order_qty where item_id=item2;
     }

    insert into order_items (order_id,item_id,qty) values (order_id,item3,order_qty );
    update item_master set pre_allocated=pre_allocated+order_qty where item_id=item3

    }
```

I want this total query in stored procedure. Please help me how to implement this in mysql stored procedure